# user permissions in windows forms

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a project in which I want to give permission to users as he can only add or update or print etc..is there any particular way of doing it or any tutorials to get idea about it. My permissions formis something like this.Can any one give idea on this like what is the right way or best approach to do this ? Im using vs 2008 vb.net windows app using sqlserver 2008

[image: .]

Comment: Why are you re-inventing security? Your database already handles this.

Comment: @SLaks Im thinking to put on each form and button to check if the current user has the permission to do this ..if no then message but I dont think thats right..thats y i posted qtn here.

Comment: @David Heffernan : I dont want to reninvent anything. Its juz dont know how to do it as Im a new to programming and thought to ask so that experienced people like u can help me. how database handles this ? Is their any tutorial or link you can provide me to do this because I have no idea about this. Users are created dynamically i.e through this form only new users will be created and admin will give permision according to his choice..so I need 1 form like above to do the requirements right?

Comment: It's a huge topic. Read the documentation for SQL server. You for sure don't want to do it yourself. You absolutely do not want to be coding a form like that. You really think you want to look after the user's passwords?

Comment: Im not giving full permissions to database. Im talking about forms and buttons on it. Im not sure if you got my question correctly. See its an accounting software and my client will create users according to his needs and staff so obviously I need above form.or if not can you please explain it little more clearly

Comment: @DavidHeffernan If you marked my qtn negative without understanding then i request you to remove that negative mark bcoz imnot able to post any other qtns.

Comment: I don't think I did downvote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While SQL server does give some user permissions settings, it sounds like you want control over this from within your app, which I can understand(I'm working on a similar project myself at the moment).  There are two ways you can do something like this:

1. On each Form_Load, disable/hide the controls on that form that the currently logged in user is not allowed to use.
2. In the handlers for different events, only run the code if the current user has permissions to use that particular function.

As others have mentioned, what you're looking to do is not a small project by any means, but it can be done.  As far as best practices for handling this, I would say whatever works for you.

Comment: this is the same solution what i was thinking of ..Is there no other easy way??Anyways thanks for ur help

Comment: The only other real alternative would be if you can find an existing toolkit/extension/etc that would give you some sort of GUI means of doing this.